# Is the full rank assumption a necessary and sufficient condition?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, random-variable, multivariate-normal-distribution

Suppose that we have the following random variables drawn by the multidimensional normal distribution, that is the vector $\mu=(v;\theta;\theta_M;u)$ where all these random variables are jointly normally distributed with mean zero and variance covariance matrix $\Omega$ as it is shown below. We have the folowing:

1. a multidimensional signal $\theta_i\in \mathbb{R}^{\kappa_i}$, where $\kappa_i \geq 0$ is the dimensionality of the signal and $\theta=(\theta_1;\theta_2;...;\theta_n)$ is the vecotr that summarizes the signals with dimensionality $K=\sum_{i}^{n}\kappa_i$. Note that the symbol semicolon denotes that every $\theta_i$ is a column vector
2. also $\theta_{\kappa_M}\in \mathbb{R}^{\kappa_M}$ where $\kappa_M \geq 0$ denotes the dimensionality of the signal and it is also a column vector
3. it is assumed without loss of generality that every variance covariance matrix of $\theta_i$ and $\theta_M$ are full rank, but it is not a restriction for the matrix $\Omega$ to be of full rank

The following matrix is the variance covriance matrix $\Omega$. My question is, why do we need the full rank assumption? Is the full rank assumption a necessary and sufficient condition to ensure the existence of the inverse variance covariance matrix? I do not see any other reason. 
[image: Variance covariance matrix]

$\underline{NOTE:}$These are assumptions of some paper that I read, but since many misunderstandings can be done of the original paper, i presented the part that I need to understand as much simple as I can.

Comment: Am I reading this question correctly that it is about whether a square matrix must be full rank to be invertible?

Comment: @Jake Westfall Well, in fact yes this is the question because othewise the inverse matrix does not exist. Non-square matrices do not have an inverse. However, in some cases such a matrix may have a left inverse or right inverse. So i thing this is the case. But it was a little confusing when i first so this structure and I wanted someone to confirm the whole skeptic